# Copying input from active tab to input of another tab that have the same name - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, tabs, clone

I have an input field in one tab and another input field with the same name in other tab. How can I repeat the inputed value in one tab to another? (I'm using Bootstrap)

To repeat inputed values, I'm using the code below, but I don't know how to load values from active tab to another.

**Click for demo:**  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6e5ca97/)

Code:

```js
$('input, textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

I have three tabs:

```html
<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"><br>
        <label for="fi">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi' name="first_input">

        <label for="si">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si' name="second_input">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><br>
        <label for="fi">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi' name="first_input">

        <label for="si">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si' name="second_input">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages"><br>
        <label for="fi">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi' name="first_input">

        <label for="si">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si' name="second_input">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and js for show tab by url for example index.html#profile:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Ids should be unique. You are repeating the ids `fi & si`. Instead use a class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the same IDs (`si` and `fi`) multiple times and they should be unique. You have to either change the ID values to unique names or use classes, because the same class name can be used multiple times.

In this case, I would use distinct IDs because you have a `label for` tag and the `for` references an ID element and not a class. ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp))

Fixed HTML code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ysmhkz2/)) using distinct IDs:

```html
<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"><br>
        <label for="fi_home">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi_home' name="first_input">

        <label for="si_home">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si_home' name="second_input">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><br>
        <label for="fi_profile">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi_profile' name="first_input">

        <label for="si_profile">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si_profile' name="second_input">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages"><br>
        <label for="fi_messages">First input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='fi_messages' name="first_input">

        <label for="si_messages">Second input</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id='si_messages' name="second_input">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```